# WinInet HttpQuery Info returning Invalid Status Codes

Tags: c++, http, wininet

I am working on a program that needs to check the existence of a page before it loads (so nothing too exotic).

Everything is working OK, but I cannot get HttpQueryInfo to return a valid status code for a page. The status code returned is: **1875378224**

Code producing the problem:

```
DWORD headerBuffSize = sizeof(DWORD);
DWORD statusCode;
//Check existance of page (for 404 error)
if(!HttpQueryInfo(hRequestHandle,
                  HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE,
                  &statusCode,
                  &headerBuffSize,
                  NULL))
    return 4;

if(statusCode == HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND)
    cout << "We got a 404 error" << endl;

cout << "Got Status code: " << statusCode << endl; //1875378224 everywhere
cout << "404 status code: " << HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND << endl; //What it should be getting
```

I am not sure what to make of it; I have compared my own code to several examples online, and it looks like it *should* work, although I may have just made a stupid mistake.

Thanks!

Comment: What does `sizeof(DWORD)` give you? Just wondering if it's some kind of odd 64/32 bit thing.

Comment: its not a problem with the DWORD itself; it seems to have something to do with the function giving me a 1 byte char array with 0 in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The information retrieved from the response header by `HttpQueryInfo` is always a text string.

```
int statusCode;
char responseText[256]; // change to wchar_t for unicode
DWORD responseTextSize = sizeof(responseText);

//Check existance of page (for 404 error)
if(!HttpQueryInfo(hRequestHandle,
                  HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE,
                  &responseText,
                  &responseTextSize,
                  NULL))
    return 4;
statusCode = atoi(responseText);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip; but now the response text is always zero :/

Also, responseTextSize must be a DWORD, but that shouldn't be what is causing the problem.

Comment: If you're compiling for Unicode change `char` to `wchar_t` as well as `atoi()`.  I've updated my answer to reflect that along with fixing the issue you pointed out ;)

Comment: Almost got it working; but the char array itself is not holding anything, and the buffer size itself is 1, and contains 0 still. Thanks for your input, very helpful.

Comment: If you call HttpOpenRequest but forget to also call HttpSendRequest after it, before calling HttpQueryInfo, you will always get a zero value for the status code.

Answer (score 17):

As other's have pointed out [HttpQueryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384238%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns the requested information as a string. You need to ensure that you have a buffer allocated large enough to retrieve the string, and, it would be up to your application to release it.

However, the same Microsoft documentation for [HttpQueryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384238%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) also hints that you can get a `DWORD` for `HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE` provided `HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER` is used.

The following code snippet shows you how:

```
DWORD statusCode = 0;
DWORD length = sizeof(DWORD);
HttpQueryInfo(
    hRequestHandle,
    HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE | HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER,
    &statusCode,
    &length,
    NULL
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just recently gotten this to work - found most of the examples on the web didn't work for me, even the ones on MSDN (possibly since my c++ is very rusty at the moment and I was making simple mistakes). This is what I have that works for me:

```
LPVOID lpOutBuffer = NULL;
DWORD dwSize = 0;

while (!HttpQueryInfo(hRequest, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE, (LPVOID)lpOutBuffer, &dwSize, NULL))    
{
    DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
    if (dwError == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
    {
        lpOutBuffer = new wchar_t[dwSize];  
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "HttpQueryInfo failed, error = %d (0x%x)\n",
            GetLastError(), GetLastError());
        break;
    }
}

wchar_t* outBuffer = (wchar_t*)lpOutBuffer;
std::wcout << L"Status_Code: " << outBuffer;

int status_code = _wtoi(outBuffer);

delete[] lpOutBuffer;
```